# Count vector elements in range when condition is met

Tags: r, vector, vectorization, sequence

I have a vector of numbers:

```
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 30, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 15, 45, 0, 0)
```

For each element `i` in `x`, I would like to do the following

1. If `x[i] > 0`, return 0
2. If all 4 elements before `x[i]` are `0`, return NA
3. If the 4 elements before `x[i]` are not `0`, count how many elements are between the last not-`0` element and `x[i]`

I expect this output:

```
#> x
#[1]  0  0  0 30 60  0  0  0  0  0 10  0  0 15 45  0  0
#> x_out
#[1] NA NA NA  0  0  1  2  3  4 NA  0  1  2  0  0  1  2
```

Notice that the solution should also work when there are less than 4 elements available at the beginning of the vector (i.e. condition 2 and 3 should use as many elements as are available). Does anybody have a solution for this? A vectorised approach is preferred because the vectors are long and the dataset is fairly big.

Comment: Why are the first 3 `NA`? You say *If all **4** elements before x[i] are 0, return NA* (I assume `x[i]` is the last non-zero value)

Comment: @Sotos What's wrong with the [tag:vectorization] tag?

Comment: See 4th last line of my question: For the positions where not 4 elements are available, the function should use as many positions as are available. So for the 1st position only 1, for the 2nd position 2, for the 3rd position 3, and from the 4th position onwards 4 positions.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I found it a bit redundant here as OP wants an operation on a single vector - Re-added it

Comment: @piptoma Ok, got it

Comment: Do you have restrictions regarding use of Rcpp? Because, since you are still working on this issue, I think it would be easiest for you to write a simple loop in Rcpp.

Comment: I have never used Rcpp, is that a restriction? :)

Comment: A solution like the one you gave me on friday would work perfectly. I like readability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple Rcpp solution. Create a new C++ file in RStudio and paste the code into it and source the file. Obviously, you'll need to have installed Rtools if you use Windows.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;    

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector funRcpp(const IntegerVector x) {
  const double n = x.length();
  int counter = 4;
  IntegerVector y(n);

  for (double i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (x(i) > 0) {
      y(i) = 0;
      counter = 0;
    }
    else {
      if (counter > 3) {
        y(i) = NA_INTEGER;
      } else {
        counter++;
        y(i) = counter;
      }
    }
  }

  return y;
}


/*** R
x <- c(0, 0, 0, 30, 60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 15, 45, 0, 0)
funRcpp(x)
*/
```

This returns the desired result:

```
> funRcpp(x)
 [1] NA NA NA  0  0  1  2  3  4 NA  0  1  2  0  0  1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my current approach:

```
library(dplyr)
last_x_months <- 4
my_list       <- vector("list", 1 + last_x_months)
my_list[[1]]  <- x

# create lagged variants of vector
for (j in seq_along(1:last_x_months)) {
  my_list[[1 + j]] <- lag(my_list[[1]], n = j, default = NA)
}

# row bind it to a data.frame
i_dat <- do.call(rbind, my_list) %>% 
  as.data.frame()

# apply function to each column in dataframe
sapply(i_dat, function(x) {
  if (sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) == 0) {
    NA
  } else if (x[1] > 0) {
    0
  } else {
    rle(x)$lengths[1]
  }
})
```

This is the output I get:

```
#> output
#[1] NA  NA  NA   0   0   1   2   3   4  NA   0   1   2   0   0   1   2
```

Is this good practice or could I improve performance with a shortcut? I am pretty inexperienced when it comes to performance optimisation, that's why I posed the question.